# executing a program from another program in C

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks

I am trying to launch a program from another program.

Here is the code below
Figure :1

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Before Execution \n");
    system("c:\\Rasmi Personal\\PERSONAL\\C\\Code Block\\C_Test\\bin\\Debug\\C_Test.exe");
    printf("\nAfter Execution \n");
    return 0;
}
```

In c:\Rasmi Personal\PERSONAL\C\Code Block\C_Test\bin\Debug\C_Test project contains the code is

Figure 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     int x = 10;
     while( x --> 0 ) // x goes to 0
     {
        printf("%d\n", x);
     } return 0;
}
```

But while executing the 1st program (Figure 1) the output comes as below.

```
Before Execution
'c:\Rasmi' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

After Execution
```

Please help me in solving this.

PS:- I am using CODE::BLOCKS in Windows XP.

Comment: @Mat: When I did the same it his error as "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: i think u have to use escape character for spaces as directory names contains spaces and the derive name "c" should be capital

Comment: @AmolSharma It might be a problem with the spaces but not with the drive name being in small letters. WIndows is case insensitive when it comes to file names

Comment: Add escape character after Rasmi like this system("c:\\Rasmi\ Personal\\PERSONAL\\C\\Code Block\\C_Test\\bin\\Debug\\C_Test.exe");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using path names with spaces in them. Everything gets more confusing when you do that, and you have to add quotes around the right things in the right places to get anything to work.

I recommend using path names without spaces in them.

If you still want to try to make this work with spaces in your path names, the following might do it:

```
system("\"c:\\Rasmi Personal\\PERSONAL\\C\\Code Block\\C_Test\\bin\\Debug\\C_Test.exe\"");
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot... It did work. But could you please the elaborate your answer a bit? I could not able to understand the statement provided by you

Comment: The Windows shell uses spaces to separate the command from its arguments. When you use `system()`, you are passing a command line to the shell. The shell sees `c:\Rasmi` followed by a space, and incorrectly concludes that there must be a `c:\Rasmi.exe` program. There isn't, so you get an error. When you put the whole thing in quotes that are passed to the shell, the shell looks in the whole path that is surrounded by the quotes, and runs that program.